# Shopify product page - update slick slider to selected variant

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I added a slick slider to Shopify's Boundless theme's product page and it properly displays the products images. The part where I'm having trouble is making the slider update to match the selected variant.
Here is the relevant JS:

```js
productVariantCallback: function(variant) {
      var $pageLink = $(selectors.pageLink, this.$container);

      if (variant) {
        if (variant.featured_image) {
           var newImg = variant.featured_image;
          var el = $(selectors.variantImage)[0];

          var $slider=$('#product-slides');
          if( $slider.length ) {
            var newImgBase = newImg.src.substring(0, newImg.src.lastIndexOf('.')).split(':').pop();

            if( $slider.hasClass('slick-initialized') ) {
              var newIndex =   $('#product-slides.slick-initialized img[src^="' + newImgBase + '"]')

              .closest('.slick-slide')
              .last()
              .data('slick-index');
              console.log( 'Goto slide ' + newIndex );
              $slider.slickGoTo( newIndex, true  );
            } else { 
              var newIndex =   $('#product-slides img').index( $('#product-slides img[src^="' + newImgBase + '"]'));
              Shopify.sliderInitAt = newIndex ;
            }
          }

// more code, but I don't believe it is relevant to the issue
```

and the relevant chunks of liquid:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product" data-history-state>

  {% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}

  {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}

  <meta itemprop="url" content="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ product.title }}{% if product.variants.size > 1 and product.selected_variant %} - {{ current_variant.title }}{% endif %}">

  <div class="page-width--wide" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" style="margin-top:20px;">

    {% assign first_image = featured_image %}

    {% if product.images.size > 1 and section.settings.skip_first_product_image and first_image == product.featured_image %}
      {% assign first_image = product.images[1] %}
    {% endif %}

   
    {% if product.images.size > 0 %}
      <div class="grid__item medium-up--three-fifths mobile-grid">
        <div id="product-slides">
            {% for image in product.images %}
            <div>
              <img class="product__photo--variant lazyload"
                   src="{{ image | img_url: 'master' }}"
                   data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                   data-widths="[360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 1944, 2048, 4472]"
                   data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
                   data-sizes="auto"
                   alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        
          <div class="slider-nav" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            {% for image in product.images %}
            <div>
              <img class="product__photo--variant lazyload"
                   src="{{ image | img_url: 'master' }}"
                   data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                   data-widths="[360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 1944, 2048, 4472]"
                   data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
                   data-sizes="auto"
                   alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <noscript>
          <img class="product__photo--variant" src="{{ first_image | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
        </noscript>
      </div>
    
    {% endif %}

    <div class="grid__item medium-up--two-fifths mobile-grid">
      <div class="grid grid--no-gutters product__details-content">
        <div class="grid__item">
         
            {% form 'product', product, id:form_id, class:form_class, data-cart-form: '' %}
          
          <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} {% unless variant.available %} disabled="disabled" {% endunless %} value="{{ variant.id }}" data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}">{{ variant.title }} - {% if variant.available %}{{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}{% else %}{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% endif %}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

          {% endform %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

coding is not at all my field, so I have no idea what I'm saying when I say: I think it might be that my images need to be indexed on the liquid side then referenced on the JS side

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.imagesmain_1_sec').slick({
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              arrows: false,
              fade: true,
              asNavFor: '.imagesmain_4_sec '
            });
            
            $('.imagesmain_4_sec').slick({
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              vertical:true,
              asNavFor: '.imagesmain_1_sec',
              dots: false,
              focusOnSelect: true,         
            });         
        }); 
     </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).